# How to get value from free text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a record from table as follow:

[image]

```
Num|value|
1|/CNY5112100309028
NAGOYA DENKI (SHENZHEN) CO.,LTD.
NDK
RM B 21/F INTERNATIONAL TRADE COMM
ERCIAL BD NANHU RD,SHENZHEN CHINA
2|/1050309244
TAEKYUNG TRADING CO.,LTD.
49-4, NUEUP-DONG, OSAN-CITY,
KR-447-160 GYEONGGI-DO
SOUTH KOREA|
```

As you can see on the picture, I need to get value "NAGOYA DENKI (SHENZHEN) CO.,LTD" for the first row, and the second row I need to get value "TAEKYUNG TRADING CO.,LTD" and so on.

As shown in the picture, the data is separated by a new line. I need to find the value between the first new line and the second new line, which is as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: If you treat your value as a delimited string, with the line breaks as the delimiter, this becomes far easier. Then you just need to remove the leading and trailing `*` characters. One method to do that (on recent versions of SQL Server) would be to use `TRIM`.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Can you clarify with more clear examples: input vs output?

Comment: What version of SQLServer

Comment: the example I mentioned earlier is 1 row record. I want to retrieve every value after writing "/XXXXX(Enter)". If you look at the example records that I mentioned, it means that I will take the data "NAGOYA DENKI (SHENZHEN) CO.,LTD" it's not enough to just use TRIM, because I have to detect the characters "/" and "enter"

Comment: Are you really trying to do parsing inside a t-sql query ? Should I really tell you how bad this is ?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Does the value actually have `CRLF` in it? Or is this just added as the previous existing `**` to make the question more difficult ?

Comment: It is not clear, from the picture. that the data is separated by a new line....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below should work for you. Replace variable with column name from your table.

```
DECLARE @YourString varchar(MAX) = '"/CNY5123456789312
NAGOYA DENKI (SHENZHEN) CO.,LTD.
NDK 
RM B 21/F INTERNATIONAL TRADE COMM
ERCIAL BD NANHU RD,SHENZHEN CHINA"';

;WITH sTRINGiNDEX AS
(
    SELECT CHARINDEX('"/', @YourString)+1+CHARINDEX(CHAR(13),RIGHT(@YourString,LEN(@YourString)-1-CHARINDEX('"/', @YourString))) AS STARTPOSITION,
           CHARINDEX(CHAR(13),RIGHT(    RIGHT(@YourString,LEN(@YourString)-1-CHARINDEX('"/', @YourString))
                , LEN(RIGHT(@YourString,LEN(@YourString)-1-CHARINDEX('"/', @YourString)))-1-CHARINDEX( CHAR(13),RIGHT(@YourString,LEN(@YourString)-1-CHARINDEX('"/', @YourString)))))+1 AS LENGTH1
)
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@YourString,STARTPOSITION,LENGTH1),CHAR(32),'') FROM sTRINGiNDEX
;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, if you use the line breaks as a delimiter, this becomes much easier. *Assuming* you are using a recent version of SQL Server with both `STRING_SPLIT` and `TRIM`:

```sql
DECLARE @YourString varchar(MAX) = '"/CNY5123456789312 CRLF
**NAGOYA DENKI (SHENZHEN) CO.,LTD. CRLF**
NDK CRLF
RM B 21/F INTERNATIONAL TRADE COMM
ERCIAL BD NANHU RD,SHENZHEN CHINA"';

SELECT TRIM('* ' FROM SS.[value]) AS YourValue
FROM (VALUES(@YourString))V(YourColumn)
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(V.YourColumn,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10)) SS --Remove carriage returns in REPLACE
WHERE SS.[value] LIKE '**%';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=42e01d6d63050c79fd9c36853f4b33d5)

Comment: My bad, Actually * character is to define Block. Ther real data without * character, as follow :
/CNY5123456789312 CRLF
NAGOYA DENKI (SHENZHEN) CO.,LTD.CRLF
NDK CRLF
RM B 21/F INTERNATIONAL TRADE COMM CRLF
ERCIAL BD NANHU RD,SHENZHEN CHINA"
and I used SQL server, i can't use TRIM, in SQL Server using LTRIM and RTRIM right?

Comment: If your sample data isn't representative then the answer(s) you are going to get are going to be wrong, @Rakhmi ... Update your question to give actual meaningful sample data.

Comment: I already update my question, Hopefully can find the answer.

Comment: @Rakhmi you've posted images of the data; I can't consume that. Post DDL and DML statements.